# Using Scala's Either, Right and Left from Java

Tags: java, scala

How might a Java program wrap a value into a scala.Either? For example, how would the following Scala code be written in Java?

```
Right("asdf")
Left(new Exception())
```

The following fails with "cannot find symbol method apply(java.lang.String)"

```
Right.apply("asdf");
```

The following fails with "cannot find symbol method apply(java.lang.Exception)"

```
Left.apply(new Exception());
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, assume you have the following Scala method:

```
def foo(stringOrDate: Either[String, Date]) {
    //...
}
```

you can call it from Java code by single creating `Either` subclasses instances:

```
scalaObject.foo(new Left<String, Date>("abc"));
scalaObject.foo(new Right<String, Date>(new Date()));
```

If you want to pass functions from Java code, you have to implement `Function*` trait depending on the function arity:

```
def foo(stringOrStringFun: Either[String, () => String]) {
    //...
}
```

In Java:

```
scalaObject.foo(new Left<String, scala.Function0<String>>("abc"));
scalaObject.foo(new Right<String, scala.Function0<String>>(
        new scala.Function0<String>() {
            @Override
            public String apply() {
                throw new RuntimeException();
            }
        }));
```

Of course in Scala it is much simpler as it supports lambdas on the syntax level:

```
foo(Left("abc"))
foo(Right(throw new RuntimeException()))
```

Comment: @MikeSlinn: I added some code snippets on how to pass code blocks from Java.

Comment: I have seen this before, and wondered what it meant:

() => String

Comment: @MikeSlinn: every time you see `=>` it means a function from something => to something. Do not confuse with `->`